# How could I write a large array into csv file Fast

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have written the following code to write a large array into csv. As I have 177700 samples and 23305 genes, so data is large in values array. This code is conceptually fine but it is very, very slow, as sample id, gene id, and values are three fields for csv file.

How could I write it to be faster?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($sample); $i++)
{
       for ($j=0; $j < count($gene); $j++)
        {
         fputcsv($f,array($sample[$i]['sample_id'],$gene[$j]['gene_id'],$values[$i][$j]));
        }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Buy a faster processor.

Comment: Do you really want to insert `177700  * 23305 = 41,26,15,025` rows inside a CSV?

Comment: Note that there's presently no mysql here. So, either revise your question or remove that tag

Comment: Where does the data come from? Are you sure that the source of your performance issues are in the posted code and not while getting the data?

Comment: yes i need to insert these no of rows

Comment: @user10510900 What's the point of repeating same `sample_id` for each of the 23305 rows? In fact, same gene data well, only with a different value in last column. I think you will need to think about restructuring  your data.

Comment: @vivkek I need data in this form because i am creating a mysql database ..and want to load the csv file into a mysql table  in which sample id is foreign key.

Comment: @user10510900 You actually typed my username wrong :p. Anyway, have you considered this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: @vivek_23 sorry for your wrong user name ...Before entering to mysql load command i need a clear csv file which i want to create form above code but its too slow take 2-3 days for 50000.I need a solutin for this.

Comment: @user10510900 Ok, how did you get this data in an array then?

Comment: _"but its too slow take 2-3 days for 50000"_ - 2-3 **_days_**? Are you running this on old calculator? Honestly, that doesn't sound like it's an issue with the posted code. It sounds like some other major performance issue.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  yes it is taking ..50000 means 50000 samples data...total no of rows will be 50000x23304=1165200000 no of rows

Comment: Why not directly insert this data in the database?

Comment: Switch to `foreach` (from `for`); it eliminates a lot of fluff (eg, $i, subscripting, etc) and probably speeds things up some.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have enough memory**

---

Write everything to memory instead of file (that is quite fast) and later flush everything to file in one action:

```
    ob_start();
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    for($i = 0; $i < count($sample); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($gene); $j++) {
            fputcsv($f,array($sample[$i]['sample_id'],$gene[$j]['gene_id'],$values[$i][$j]));
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
    $csvText = ob_get_clean();

    file_put_contents($filePath, $csvText);
```

---

If you are inserting this to DB, then why not do it directly in batches? Saves time from writing to file > reading file > writing to SQL > executing as SQL.

```
$inserts = [];
$batchSize = 10000; // Adjust to your resources

$sqlStart = '';

for($i = 0; $i < count($sample); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($gene); $j++) {
        $inserts[] = "('{$sample[$i]['sample_id']}', '{$gene[$j]['gene_id']}', '{$values[$i][$j]}')";

        if (count($inserts) == $batchSize) {
            saveToDb($inserts);
            $inserts = [];
        }
    }
 }

 // Save if any left in last batch
 saveToDb($inserts);

 function saveToDb(array $inserts) {
     if (empty($inserts)) {
         return;
     }

     $sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table (`sample_id`, `gene_id`, `value`) VALUES ';

     $sql .= implode(',', $inserts);
     MyPdoClass::execute($sql);
 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208834/discussion-on-answer-by-justinas-how-could-i-write-a-large-array-into-csv-file-f).